# How to store session in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, httpsession

What's the best way of storing session related data of a user (like, for example a log of recent actions a user has done) in a Spring MVC (2.5) web application ?

Using the classic javax.servlet.http.HttpSession or by specifying scope="session" in controller beans, and storing the data in a session object ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Session-scoped beans (using `scope="session"`) is the cleanest approach. This removes the need to interact with the session yourself.

If you want to autowire a session-scoped bean in to the controller, you either need to make the controller session-scoped itself, or use a scoped-proxy to wire it into a singleton controller, as [described here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection). Either approach is valid.

Comment: thank you, a cleaner approach was exactly what i was searching for

Comment: Thankyou for this excellent answer, I had been using the HttpSession directly up until now.

Making the Controller Request scoped (ie the old Throwaway Controller) also works and avoids the need for the scoped-proxy. Are there any downsides to this?

Comment: @Dick: request-scoped beans bring a performance penalty, but as long as your controller doesn't have an expensive custom init process, or your traffic isn't too high, it shouldn't be significant.

Comment: can you please provide an example of work with session-scoped beans in the controller?